# Print separate word string horizontally

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, printing

I'm beginner just start learning python and this is really confusing me because i want to test practicing using string.

[image]

The output should be like above. The spacing between two columns is one tab.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a another approach with list comprehension.

```
words = ["groceries", "restaurant", "hotel"]

max_length = max(len(word) for word in words)  

for i in range(max_length):
    output_line = "    ".join([word[i] if len(word) > i else " " for word in words])
    print(output_line)
```

output:

```
g    r    h
r    e    o
o    s    t
c    t    e
e    a    l
r    u     
i    r     
e    a     
s    n     
     t
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) for the task:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest


def print_words(words):
    for t in zip_longest(*words, fillvalue=" "):
        print(*t, sep=" ")


words = ["groceries", "restaurant", "hotel"]
print_words(words)
```

Prints:

```
g r h
r e o
o s t
c t e
e a l
r u  
i r  
e a  
s n  
  t
```

Comment: best approach here. Upvote if you give more details to the function since OP is a beginner

Comment: thanks for answering but what is *t for?

Comment: @Rizard That depends on the context, but here it means unpacking the `t` tuple as parameters to `print`. So every tuple from `zip_longest` are unpacked as parameters in `print`

Comment: ok thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic approach not using any other modules.

```
strings=["groceries","restaurant","hotel"]

# detect longest string
string_max=0
for s in strings:
 if len(s)>string_max: string_max=len(s)

# print the strings
for i in range(string_max):
 # put the i-th character of each string in a list
 c=[]
 for s in strings:
  try:
   c.append(s[i])
  except:  # is the string is too short, an index error will be thrown
   c.append(" ")
 # print the list of characters per each line
 print ("\t".join(c))
```

Output:

```
g       r       h
r       e       o
o       s       t
c       t       e
e       a       l
r       u
i       r
e       a
s       n
        t
```

Of course this can still be enhanced using e.g. list comprehension, but for a basic approach this works.

Comment: thanks for answer, but when i test the output is just 't'

Comment: How did you use it? I just tested it in python CLI and the output was as given above. Did you check to have `"\t"` in double quotes?

Comment: ok, my fault i didn't paste correctly. Thanks